# Should I mention the names of several professors that I want to work with in my statement of purpose? (US)

Tags: graduate-admissions

### Background

I am a second (and final) year Master's degree student (with thesis) in my university's Electrical and Computer Engineering (ECE) department. I am currently trying to shift my career focus from ECE to Machine Learning (ML). More precisely, I am taking courses related to theoretical ML and I am currently undertaking research using applied ML techniques.

I am currently trying to apply to PhD programs in theoretical ML. I am only interested in a small subset of theoretical ML, namely Reinforcement Learning and interpretable ML. However, I don't have any research experience in either of these two fields or in theoretical ML as a whole. I only have experience in applying ML techniques to existing problems. I have 1 paper published from my undergraduate degree in an unrelated field (electromagnetics).

### The Questions

- If I am applying to a university that has faculty that work in both of these fields, how can I phrase my statement of purpose to reflect that I am interested in working for both of them?
- How much do I need to explain about where my interest in these two fields comes from? Do I need to write a paragraph or just mention their names?
- Is it ok that my interest does not stem from past research experience but from reading papers and watching YouTube videos related to this field?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is probably more important that you focus on the subfield you want to work in than the individuals involved.

Comment: @Buffy I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean that it is not important to mention their names at all and write more about the fields I am interested in?

Comment: I don't know your field well enough to give a real answer, but it occurs to me that focusing on the field instead of individuals leaves options open. In some fields you get hired by PIs for your funding so it is necessary to name them (and apply to them). And things can be a bit different with an MS. Hopefully someone in your field can provide more help.